# Using own.hit Object List? with ["Near"] sensor

Tags: python

When using  own.hit Object  List  how  do  you  print  out  the  chosen  item.  I mean  how  do  you  go  thought  the  list  with  the  python  system. Is  it print(own.hit Object List[0],[10])
or  something   like  that?......., and  then  receive  a  print  out . I  could use  the  info. i need for the a.i to chose the farthest object and track_to it trying to use Near sensor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
from bge import logic

if logic.getCurrentController.sensors['Near'].positive:
    for obj in controller.sensors['Near'].hitObjectList:
        print(obj)
```

[KX_NearSensor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_NearSensor.html?highlight=sensor#bge.types.KX_NearSensor)

[KX_TouchSensor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_RaySensor.html?highlight=hit%20object#bge.types.KX_RaySensor.hitObject)